# Store data locally on app close, not when put into background

Tags: java, android, mobile

I am working on an app that i want the user to be able to run it in the background, but i need to save some data whenever the app is completely closed.  I have been looking at using SharedPreferences.  I am having issues with onPause() and onStop() since those are called whenever the app is put in the background.  I need to save data only when the app is completely closed and not when the user brings another app to the foreground and puts mine in the background.

Comment: you can use `onDestroy()` for that, but it won't be called if your app is *killed* instead of normal close

Comment: " I need to save data only when the app is completely closed and not when the user brings another app to the foreground and puts mine in the background." -- no, you need to save the data when the data changes.

Answer (score 0):

That's not how Android works.  You could be closed entirely hours from now.  Or weeks. Or not at all and the user turns off the phone causing you to never save.  The entire design of Android and its Activities is such that you should always be able to restore your state, and you shouldn't know or care that your app is being terminated.  In fact there is no signal that an application is being terminated.

You could try doing it in onDestroy, but it isn't really a great idea.  There's situations where onDestroy is not called.